# The Israeli MOH databases on Covid patient numbers have a lower cutoff value on published numbers of patients. How does this protect privacy?

Tags: privacy

The Israeli ministry of health reports many statistics on Covid patients (Numbers of confirmed cases, hospitalizations, people in quarantine - Divided by age and other demographics) available [here](https://data.gov.il/dataset/covid-19) (Albeit only in Hebrew)

In any category, numbers below 15 are reported as <15 (see e.g. [this](https://data.gov.il/dataset/covid-19/resource/6253ce68-5f31-4381-bb4e-557260d5c9fc?view_id=f5b76116-49f2-44dd-961b-cc16a996ae65) table, with statistics on medical personnel cases). Someone told me this was for privacy protection reasons, but I don't understand why.

Does this make sense? How is privacy compromised if exact low numbers are published?

Comment: This is more of a data science issue. The problem is when you can correlate data sets and reduce a *combination* of results down to a single individual.

Answer (score 0):

It means any number lower than 15 is sufficiently small over a sufficiently large feature space so that identifiable data can be inferred by brute force reverse engineering.